# printing multiple columns of a table using R program

Tags: r

I want to load an excel into r and print multiple columns of the table.

i was able to load the excel file and print the entire table or a single column but unable to print 2 or more columns of the table.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I want to use the column names to print them rather and using the column number

Answer (score 4):

This question will probably be taken down soon but I think what youre looking for is not using this:

```
dt[, 1,2,3]
```

But something like this:

```
dt[, c(1, 2, 3)] 
dt[, 1:5]
```

and so on :)